# Inserir (Valor)"value" do Slider dentro de um Label Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

Galera, estou com um problema nos meus estudos em Nativescript/Angular, estou tentando inserir um valor de um Slider dentro de uma Label o slider está no seguinte:

```
                    <Slider value="1" minValue="0" maxValue="100"
                        (valueChange)="onSliderValueChange($event)">
                    </Slider>
```

E o arquivo TS está o seguinte:

```
    onSliderValueChange(args) {
        let slider = <Slider>args.object;
        console.log(`valor recebido do Slider ${args.value}`);   
    }
```

Até então tudo de tranquilo, e no console mostra o valor do slider( ${args.value} ) mas eu não entendi como eu faço para manipular o elemento text dentro da label para inserir esse valor.

Como tá o meu Label:

```
<Label id="label1" text="Valor do Slider Aqui" textWrap="true"></Label>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Pois o exemplo mostrado na documentação não me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

Faz Assim:

```
               <Slider [value]="value" minValue="0" maxValue="100"
                    (valueChange)="onSliderValueChange($event)">
                </Slider>
```

TS:

```
 value=1

 constructor(){}...


onSliderValueChange(args) {
    let slider = <Slider>args.object;
   this.value=args.value;  
}
```

Comment: Acho que eu não fui muito claro, desculpe, eu preciso saber como eu manipulo o elemento text do Label para inserir nele o valor do Slider.

Comment: O valor do slider fica atribuido a propriedade value do seu componente entendeu?

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Comment: @JonataSantos, se for possível, escolha esta resposta como a melhor.